# Python qt - select random item on combo box?

Tags: python, random

How could I select random item on combo box, when button is pressed?

Sorry, I realy have no clue how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your custom mouse event, so when pressing it will randomly select the selected item index:

```
import random
class RandComboBox(QComboBox):
    ...
    def mousePressEvent (self, QMouseEvent e):
        self.setCurrentIndex(random.randint(0, self.count()))
```

Comment: Works great. But it sometimes selects empty space. Anyway to fix that?

Comment: looks like you have an empty item in you combobox, just delete it.